# Recursive case class play json lazyRead

Tags: json, scala, deserialization, playback, recursive-datastructures

In `JsPath.scala` the description of `lazyRead` method is as follows :

```
/*case class User(id: Long, name: String, friend: User)

implicit lazy val UserReads: Reads[User] = (
  (__ \ 'id).read[Long] and
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'friend).lazyRead(UserReads)
)(User.apply _) */ 

def lazyRead[T](r: => Reads[T]): Reads[T] = Reads(js => Reads.at[T]
(this)(r).reads(js))
```

when I try to execute a simplifed version of above example :

```
case class User(id:Int, user: User)

val userJsVal = Json.parse(
  """
    | {
    |   "id" : 22,
    |   "user" : { "id":2  }
    | }
  """.stripMargin)


implicit lazy val UserReads: Reads[User] = (
        (__ \ 'id).read[Int] and
         ( __ \ 'user).lazyRead(UserReads)
        )(User.apply _)

val us = Json.fromJson[User](userJsVal)(UserReads);
us match {
   case s:JsSuccess[User] => println(s.get)
   case e:JsError =>  println(JsError.toJson(e).toString()) }
```

I get the error :

```
{"obj.user.user":[{"msg":["error.path.missing"],"args":[]}]}
```

I tried setting innermost "user" to null but that did not work either. How should I frame my json or add terminating conditions in :

```
( __ \ 'user).lazyRead(UserReads)
```

to get a valid deserialized output ?

Comment: also tried the code  [https://gist.github.com/mandubian/6046786]  which gives following error :                                                                                                                                    ``forward reference extends over definition of value treeReads
[error]            ( __ \ "l").lazyRead(treeReads) and
[error]         ``                       ^

Comment: IMHO `case class User(id: Int, user: Option[User])` would be more safe definition to avoid missing of checking for null and NPE in runtime

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Andriy, your User object has to have an Option[User] otherwise your inner object will always need to have another user ad infinitum.
And you can notice that on your JSON sample the internal user already doesn't have another user underneath it. 
Then after you change the inner user to be optional, you should use lazyReadNullable, here is your sample fixed:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, JsSuccess, Json, Reads}
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class User(id:Int, user: Option[User])

val userJsVal = Json.parse(
  """
    | {
    |   "id" : 22,
    |   "myuser" : { "id":2  }
    | }
  """.stripMargin)


implicit lazy val UserReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ 'id).read[Int] and
    ( __ \ 'myuser).lazyReadNullable(UserReads)
  )(User.apply _)

val us = Json.fromJson[User](userJsVal)(UserReads)

us match {
  case s:JsSuccess[User] => println(s.get)
  case e:JsError =>  println(JsError.toJson(e).toString()) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bounded in selection of JSON-parsers, then try [`jsoniter-scala`](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) - it has built-in support of recursive structures and many other goodies, like [the best  performance characteristics comparing to other JSON parsers for Scala](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json).